# How do I force a line to start a new page in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a thesis in Microsoft Word.

I want to be able to say select the line that says "Chapter 3 Methodology" and somehow set that to automatically shift to the top of the following page such that each chapter begins at the top of a page. I've been exploring the option with no luck and I've checked online but haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is

1. ensure that each chapter heading uses the same *Paragraph Style*. e.g. select the heading, then in the Home tab, Styles group, click the style you want to use (it would typically be "Heading 1" or "Heading 2" for a chapter heading on an English-language copy of Word). Then do the same for each other Chapter heading.
2. Edit the Paragraph Style's properties (as follows):
3. right-click on the style name in the Home->Styles group.
4. click the *Modify...* menu option
5. click the *Format* button at the bottom left of the dialog box
6. Select the *Paragraph...* option
7. click the *Line and Page Breaks* tab at the top of the dialog
8. ensure the *Page break before* box is checked

Always use the same style when you create new Chapter Headings.

Answer (score 1):

> such that each chapter begins at the top of a page.

There is no such auto-feature in Microsoft Word. You have to set each chapter separately on new page yourself.

> select the line that says "Chapter 3 Methodology" and somehow set that to automatically shift to the top of the following page

- Place the cursor before the line, say, "Chapter 3 Methodology"
- `Menu > Insert > Page Break`

[image]

Comment: I believe OP is referring to bookmarking or intra-document hyperlink navigation (or whatever it's called in O365).  I recall it can be done in .pdf converted from a .docx file, but I don't remember if Word has the capability natively or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
each chapter begins at the top of a page.
```

As XPT says, there is no such feature in word.

As a workaround, you can use headers for a similar purpose

You don't need to do paging, etc., just insert the header and then select "Field" in Quick Parts.

[image]

Then select "Links and References" - "StyleRef" - "Title"

[image]

The title of each chapter will automatically appear in the title